# Sending mass emails from Excel list using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to automate a manual process, using a VBA script in Excel. I have a spreadsheet which contains 4 list of: email addresses, subject, message, signature. I am new to VBA and want to press a command button which will automatically create outlook emails for the lists.

In my example below I have a list of 3 people I am trying to send an email too by clicking button 3, I prefer too have these emails sat in my drafts and not automatically sent as they need to be checked beforehand.

[image]

below is my code

[image]

```
Public Sub SendOutlookEmails()
'Microsoft Outlook XX.X Object Library is required to run this code
'Variable declaration
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim lCounter As Long
'Set objects
Set objOutlook = Outlook.Application
'Read details from Excel sheet and send emails
For lCounter = 6 To 8
    'Create a new email item
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    'To
    objMail.To = Sheet1.Range("A" & lCounter).Value
    'Subject
    objMail.Subject = Sheet1.Range("C" & lCounter).Value
    'Email Body
    objMail.Body = Sheet1.Range("D" & lCounter).Value
    'Send email
    'objMail.Send
    'Close the object
   'Set objMail = Nothing
   End Sub
```

any help or working examples would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: [Edit] your question and paste your code in. Then select the code and tap Ctrl+K>

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Mail-merge-using-an-Excel-spreadsheet-858C7D7F-5CC0-4BA1-9A7B-0A948FA3D7D3

Comment: thanks, this could be an option but it looks like I need to have the email addresses saved or pre-set beforehand. In my case the email addresses will be different every time I execute the button as this comes from an export from another application. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

User D, I'd say use a *With* statement first for speed and readability. Then, there's a *[Save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.save?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm1326)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)* method that will save as Draft in the current NameSpace (your default email accounts' *Draft* folder - as you might have several email accounts on your Client, and are each considered their own NameSpace). If you use *.Send* method, it will send likewise if you use *.Display* method, it will not send, but popup on your screen (and will appear as another Task in Taskmgr).

```
Sub DraftEmails()

    Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim oM As Outlook.MailItem

    Set oM = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With oM
        .To = "someone@somewhere.somedomain"
        .Save
    End With

End Sub
```

Also, to be more dynamic, I'd consider using a combination of *UsedRange.Columns* & the *Find* method. This would allow you to say, locate in Column A, the cell that has "to" in it, then can iterate down from there. So if you adjusted your columns, let's say, this would catch it and your code wouldn't need adjusted.

Let us know if this answered what you need, or of any other guidance we can give.

Danny,

[ExcelVBADude](http://youtube.com/channel/UC5Z93LJulIuAICkZMSmcbGA)

Comment: Thanks Danny, The tricky part is that the emails will always be different every time I execute the button. The email address come from an export from another application so, I will need a way to not have these hardcoded in. Sorry I am new to this